# Однонаправленый линейный список

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Прошу помощи с заданием. Ввести с клавиатуры предложение и переписать его символы в однонаправленный линейный список.

С помощью этого списка скопировать в другой однонаправленный список `K` символов, начиная с позиции `N`. Список:

```
typedef struct list
{ 
    char val;
    struct list *next;
} listn, *listp;
```

Comment: И как переписать символы в список с клавиатуры? В обратном или в прямом порядке ввода? Кстати сказать в c++ уже есть односвязный список std::forward_list

Comment: Мы нажимаем кнопки на клавиатуре, соответствующие символы заносятся в список. В прямом порядке.

Comment: То есть символы добавляются в конец списка?

Comment: Как я понял, единственное, что вам осталось сделать, это нажать кнопки!:)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В С++ не нужны конструкции вида `typedef struct X_ {} X, *PX;`, вместо этого используется обычная `struct X {};`.
Также в С++ есть конструкторы, поэтому в своем простейшем виде список выглядит так:

```
struct list {
  explicit list(char val = 0, list* next = nullptr) : val(val), next(next) {}

  char val;
  list* next;
};
```

У односвязного списка есть две основные операции:
1) добавление элемента в начало

```
void push_front(list*& list_head, list* new_element) {
  new_element->next = list_head;
  list_head = new_element;
}
```

2) и удаление элемента из начала списка

```
list* pop_front(list*& list_head) {
  auto element = list_head;
  if (list_head) list_head = list_head->next;
  if (element) element->next = nullptr;
  return element;
}
```

При помощи этих операций можно сделать другие полезные операции, а именно:
Чтение списка из потока ввода:

```
list* read() {
  list* reversed_list_head = nullptr;
  char c;
  while (std::cin >> c)
    push_front(reversed_list_head, new list(c));
  return reversed_list_head;
}
```

Разворот списка:

```
void reverse(list*& list_head) {
  list* reversed_list_head = nullptr;
  while (auto element = pop_front(list_head))
    push_front(reversed_list_head, element);
  list_head = reversed_list_head;
}
```

Печать списка:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, list* list_head) {
  for (auto element = list_head; element != nullptr; element = element->next)
    stream << element->val;
  return stream;
}
```

Удаление списка:

```
void free(list* list_head) {
  while (auto element = pop_front(list_head))
    delete element;
}
```

При помощи этих функций можно написать программу:

```
int main() {
  auto list_head = read();
  reverse(list_head);
```

Так как элементы всегда добавляются в начало, то при вводе символов с клавиатуры список окажется перевернутым, и его надо перевернуть.

Далее, мы перемещаемся на `N` символов вперед (или меньше, если список короче):

```
const auto N = 2;
auto list_middle = list_head;
for (auto i = 0; i != N && list_middle != nullptr; ++i)
  list_middle = list_middle->next;
```

Затем копируем `K` элементов в новый список (или меньше, если список короче).
Т.к. мы всегда вставляем элементы в начало, то копия будет перевернутой, и ее надо будет перевернуть.

```
const auto K = 3;
list* list_copy = nullptr;
for (auto i = 0; i != K && list_middle != nullptr; ++i) {
  push_front(list_copy, new list(list_middle->val));
  list_middle = list_middle->next;
}
reverse(list_copy);
```

Выводим копию списка на печать:

```
std::cout << "list copy: " << list_copy << std::endl;
```

И наконец удаляем оба списка

```
free(list_copy);
free(list_head);
```

Тут можно посмотреть [>>>весь код<<<](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d99b9168fdd2d318).